# How to create Kotlin DSL - DSL syntax Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension, anko

As with [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) you can write callback functions like this:

```
alert {
    title = ""
    message = ""
    yesButton {
       toast("Yes") 
    }
    noButton { 
       toast("No")
    }
}
```

How can I create a nested functions like that? I tried creating it like below but doesn't seem to be working.

```
class Test {
    fun f1(function: () -> Unit) {}
    fun f2(function: () -> Unit) {}
}
```

Now, if I use this with extension function,

```
fun Context.temp(function: Test.() -> Unit) {
    function.onSuccess() // doesn't work
}
```

Calling this from Activity:

```
temp {
    onSuccess {
        toast("Hello")
    }
}
```

Doesn't work. I am still lacking some basic concepts here. Can anyone guide here?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Kotlin DSLs

Kotlin is great for writing your own **Domain Specific Languages**, also called [type-safe builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html). As you mentioned, the Anko library is an example making use of DSLs. The most important language feature you need to understand here is called ["Function Literals with Receiver"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver), which you made use of already: `Test.() -> Unit`

### Function Literals with Receiver - Basics

Kotlin supports the concept of “function literals with receivers”. This enables calling visible methods on the **receiver** of the function literal in its body *without any specific qualifiers*. This is very **similar to extension functions**, in which it’s also possible to access members of the receiver object inside the extension.

A simple example, also one of the coolest functions in the Kotlin standard library, is`apply`:

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T { block(); return this }
```

As you can see, such a function literal with receiver is taken as an argument `block` here. This `block` is simply executed and the receiver (which is an instance of `T`) is returned. In action this looks as follows:

```
val text: String = StringBuilder("Hello ").apply {
            append("Kotliner")
            append("! ")
            append("How are you doing?")
        }.toString()
```

A `StringBuilder` is used as the receiver and `apply` is invoked on it. The `block`, passed as an argument in `{}`(lambda expression), does not need to use additional qualifiers and simply calls `append`, a visible method of `StringBuilder` multiple times.

### Function Literals with Receiver - in DSL

If you look at this example, taken from the documentation, you see this in action:

```
class HTML {
    fun body() { ... }
}

fun html(init: HTML.() -> Unit): HTML {
    val html = HTML()  // create the receiver object
    html.init()        // pass the receiver object to the lambda
    return html
}


html {       // lambda with receiver begins here
    body()   // calling a method on the receiver object
}
```

The `html()` function expects such a function literal with receiver with `HTML` as the receiver. In the function body you can see how it is used: an instance of `HTML` is created and the `init` is called on it.

### Benefit

The caller of such an *higher-order function* expecting a function literal with receiver (like `html()`) you can use any visible `HTML` function and property without additional qualifiers (like `this` e.g.), as you can see in the call:

```
html {       // lambda with receiver begins here
    body()   // calling a method on the receiver object
}
```

### Your Example

I created a simple example of what you wanted to have:

```
class Context {
    fun onSuccess(function: OnSuccessAction.() -> Unit) {
        OnSuccessAction().function();
    }

    class OnSuccessAction {
        fun toast(s: String) {
            println("I'm successful <3: $s")
        }
    }
}

fun temp(function: Context.() -> Unit) {
    Context().function()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    temp {
        onSuccess {
            toast("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need some time to understand this. Not getting straight into my head :/

Comment: What exactly is hard to get for you, let me provide more info then?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have a look in the night and then let you know

Comment: Ok cool. I've extended the description a little bit. The core concept to understand is "function literals with receiver", aka "lambda with receiver"

Comment: Thanks :) I will have a look

Comment: I understand a little bit. Let's say, `temp` is the context function. Now you are calling `onSuccess` method of `temp` (Context). Until this is fine. Now going inside it confuses me totally.. :/

Comment: Let's say I am trying to create a syntax like this for an interface with 2 callbacks. Like retrofit callback, textwatcher etc..

Comment: Right, first you call ``onSuccess`` (Method of ``Context``) then you call ``toast`` (Method of ``OnSuccessAction``)

Comment: Got it! Thanks! :)

Comment: That's great. I know, it requires another way of thinking and isn't that easy actually. Good luck anyways :)

Comment: Once you get there, it seems easy. But it was first time, so took a little time for me. Also created something like this with listeners..

Comment: That's great and totally fine, congrats

Answer (score 1):

In your example alert is the function returning some class, for example Alert.
Also this function takes as parameter function literal with receiver

In your example you should make your
onSuccess the member method of your Test class, and your temp function should return instance of Test class without invoking it.
But to have toast to be invoked as in your desire, it has to be member function of whatever class is returned by onSuccess

I think you don't understand exactly how functional literals with receiver work.
When you have fun(something : A.() -> Unit) it means that this "something" is the member function of A class.

So

You can look at my blog post : [How to make small DSL for AsyncTask](https://jankotlin.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/async_lazy_kotliniers/)