# difference between fun in companion object block and outside of class in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning kotlin and has recently spotted an interesting way of writing kotlin but can't really understand it.

taken the code I'm learning from [here](https://github.com/zsmb13/MaterialDrawerKt/blob/master/library/src/main/java/co/zsmb/materialdrawerkt/imageloader/DrawerImageLoaderKt.kt)

```
fun drawerImageLoader(actions: DrawerImageLoaderKt.() -> Unit): DrawerImageLoader.IDrawerImageLoader {
    val loaderImpl = DrawerImageLoaderKt().apply(actions).build()
    DrawerImageLoader.init(loaderImpl)
    return loaderImpl
}

class DrawerImageLoaderKt {
    ...
}
```

why should `drawerImageLoader` defined outside of class? why can't be in the class and within `companion object` block?

Also, what does `.()` mean in `DrawerImageLoaderKt.()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is defined outside the class to provide some kind of factory for `DrawerImageLoader.IDrawerImageLoader` objects, so it's not bound to concrete instances.

The syntax `DrawerImageLoaderKt.()` defines a [*Lambda with Receiver*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver), which I described in this thread: [How to create nested function callbacks like anko - DSL syntax Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113833/how-to-create-nested-function-callbacks-like-anko-dsl-syntax-kotlin/46114818#46114818)

A *Lambda with Receiver* enables us to call methods on a receiver (here: `DrawerImageLoaderKt`) of the function literal in its body without any specific qualifiers (That's what a caller of `drawerImageLoader` will do). This is very similar to extension functions, where it’s also possible to access members of the receiver object inside the extension.

Answer (score 4):

Oh hey, this is my library :)

The `drawerImageLoader` function is defined as a package level function so that it can be invoked without prefixing it (as you'd have to do if it was an instance or `object` method). This gives you the following syntax when you call it (see the code [here](https://github.com/zsmb13/MaterialDrawerKt/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/zsmb/materialdrawerktexample/DrawerApplication.kt)):

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    drawerImageLoader {
        set {
            ...
        }
        cancel {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If it was in a regular or companion object, it would look like this instead, which I believe makes for a less nice DSL:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    SomeClass.drawerImageLoader {
        set {
            ...
        }
        cancel {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

As for the type of its parameter, @s1m0nw1 already mostly answered that part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47600909/4465208), but I'll add just a bit more.

It's a lambda with a receiver, which places you in the scope of a `DrawerBuilderKt` inside the lambda that you're passing to the `drawerImageLoader` function. Since this class has `set`, `cancel`, and `placeholder` methods, these become available to use inside the lambda.

Comment: wow! great lib!! I've finished the basics tutorial in learning kotlin and am now reading your repo to get more understanding on how to write in kotlin