# Invoking a common method on multiple receivers

Tags: kotlin

Often, I have the following pattern:

```
a.x()
a.y()
a.z()
```

Kotlin offers a convenient alternative:

```
a.run { x(); y(); z() }
```

Sometimes I have a pattern like this:

```
a.x()
b.x()
c.x()
```

I want to write something like this:

```
applyTo(a, b, c) { it.x() }
```

So I might implement the following:

```
fun <P> applyTo(vararg ps: P, fx: (P) -> Unit) = ps.forEach { fx(it) }
```

Or alternately, something like this:

```
::x.eachOf(a, b, c)
```

So I could implement the function:

```
fun <P, R> ((P) -> R).eachOf(vararg p: P) = p.forEach { this(it) }
```

Is there a way to invoke a shared method on multiple receivers using the standard library, or a better way to shorten Pattern #2?

Comment: Are a, b, c the same types?

Comment: Yes, or at least they share an interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a list:

```
listOf(a, b, c).forEach { it.x() }
```

Comment: `listOf` was my first guess, and probably the best one. I wish Kotlin had collection literals. All this extra ceremony just to avoid six extra characters. Thanks!

Comment: `All this extra ceremony just to avoid six extra characters` that's what I think when I see a language WITH collection literals :)

Comment: They're coming (collection literals)... 1.2 introduced them for arrays in Annotations, and did some behind the scenes work to prepare for general introduction.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your `a,b,c` are of the same type. You can modify your `applyTo` to accept a [lambda with receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114818/8073652) and make the call look like in `run`:

```
fun <P> applyTo(vararg ps: P, fx: P.() -> Unit) = ps.forEach { it.fx() }
//call without it.x()
applyTo(a, b, c) { x() }
```

Your second solution is interesting but not very readable imho. Would not do that.