# Kotlin closure to solve logical and operation

Tags: kotlin, closures

i want to create a closure where it take all the Boolean expression and methods, gives the final result
something like this

```
  myAnd{
    23<34
    false
    someFunction() //returns true
    }
```

so the answer will be false

The solution i came with is this

```
fun myAnd(vararg flags: Boolean) = flags.all { it }

myAnd(true , false ,someFunction())
```

but this solution won't give the power of short circuiting while using and operator

Answer (score 3):

## Using blocks to implement short-circuiting and

```
fun someFunction() = true

fun and(vararg parameters: ()->Boolean): Boolean {
    return parameters.all { it() }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    and (
            {23<34},
            {false},
            ::someFunction
    )
}
```

This works by passing in each predicate as a block, which means that they can be evaluated one by one, and if any of them returns false then all will return false immediately, short-circuiting the rest of them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but is there any way to make it idiomatic by using closure  rather than passing lambdas as an argument of the method

Comment: This _is_ the more idiomatic solution. You really want 3 closures here, not 1, because using the single closure like this is equivalent to `{ someFunction() }`: it just evaluates the first 2 lines and ignores their values.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a quick solution that enables the following use:

```
val boolResult: Boolean = myAnd {
    + (23 < 34)
    + false
    + someFunction() //returns true
}
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
fun myAnd(bb: BooleanBuilder.() -> Unit) = BooleanBuilder().apply { bb() }.result

class BooleanBuilder {
    var bools = listOf<Boolean>()
    operator fun Boolean.unaryPlus() {
        bools += this
    }

    fun result() = bools.all { it }
}
```

Explanation: It's a lightweight example of a custom DSL. The interesting part of this is `BooleanBuilder.() -> Unit`, a [function literal with receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114818/8073652), so that I can pass a lambda that's in the scope of a `BooleanBuilder` (lambda's receiver). This is necessary to use the member extension `Boolean.unaryPlus` that again enables the use of `+ boolean` as shown.

Comment: this Solution worked for me as expected but can you please give a little explanation of function myAdd and how it works and This solution doesn't follow short-circuiting

Comment: added a brief explanation