# what does "lambda@" mean in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

From there: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified

we have a code like so:

```
val funLit = lambda@ fun String.() {}
```

Run there https://pl.kotl.in/Syah1jaIN it compiles and is called without error

I thought "lambda@" was an annotation but the documentation here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html
refers to a syntax sorta like "@word", not "word@".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed a label and is especially useful in that example as it labels an anonymous function. You use the label for qualifying references (like `this`).

In the following example the lambda defines an inner method `nested` which may want to access the `this` from the `funLit`. Since it is anonymous we need to label it, `lambda` is an arbitrary identifier.

```
fun main() {
    val funLit = lambda@ fun String.() {
        println("this:        " + this)
        println("this@lambda: " + this@lambda)

        fun String.nested() {
            println("this        in String.nested(): " + this)
            println("this@nested in String.nested(): " + this@nested)
            println("this@lambda in String.nested(): " + this@lambda)
        }

        "nested".nested()
    }
    "funLit".funLit()
}
```

Running it shows very clearly what `this` is being referred to with the qualifier.

```
this:        funLit
this@lambda: funLit
this        in String.nested(): nested
this@nested in String.nested(): nested
this@lambda in String.nested(): funLit
```

Here is a playground link: https://pl.kotl.in/SJrlUs6LE

Answer (score 2):

These are called **labels**. Consider this example. The `with` accepts a receiver (`StringBuilder` here) and a lambda with receiver (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114818/8073652)). Inside that second argument, the lambda expression, `this` refers to the `StringBuilder`. So if you `print(this)` it's the same as the qualified `print(this@with)`. The qualified `this` makes sense when you want to access outer `this` references like from the enclosing instance of `Outer`:

```
class Outer{
    fun someFunction() = with(StringBuilder()){
        println(this)
        println(this@with) //same as this
        println(this@Outer)
    }
}
```

It's also possible to set custom labels:

```
fun someFunction() = with(StringBuilder()) customLabel@{
    println(this@customLabel) //same as this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an annotation, but a label: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#break-and-continue-labels

It's commonly used in lambdas and loops, e.g. to jump out of nested loop.